# how to convert string to 12 bit binary without change it's value in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I want to Convert given string to 12 bit binary without changing it's value
For ex : if My string is 101010101010 then my binary must be same as string value(101010101010).. i take binary(12) as datatype in sql server

Comment: As far as i can understand you are asking about type casting right?

Comment: What is with all those tags? Which language?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: i have taken 12 checkbox if checkbox is checked then it will be consider as 1 else 0 and i store that value in one string and then combine it with next checkbox value. and in last i convertes into binary memberdetails = Convert.ToByte(a);

Comment: with the edit: can you clarify - why are you using `binary(12)` (which is a 12 **byte** value) to store a 12 **bit** value? that's 8 times too big! I mean, sure you could store the ASCII byte values, so {49, 48, 49,48, 49,48, 49,48, 49,48, 49,48} - but that doesn't sound like a great idea when the `int` database date type would work just fine - and if you *wanted* to use that approach, `char(12)` would be a more obvious choice than `binary(12)` (although still a bad choice)

Comment: @MarcGravell i know it but i have to create same database as Previous one.once it made i have to copy data from previous database..and client don't Want To  change anuthing

Comment: @DevendraPadhiyar o...k... I'll add an edit; you might want to clarify what you see as the intended output, though - is it the bytes {49, 48, 49,48, 49,48, 49,48, 49,48, 49,48} , or is it the bytes {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0} ?

Comment: (either way: edit added)

Answer (score 1):

.NET doesn't have specifically a 12-bit binary type, but `int` works just fine...

```cs
int i = Convert.ToInt32("101010101010", 2);
```

which gives the same binary value, 0b101010101010 - aka decimal 2730. It *looks* different, but... if you wanted a `string`, *you already had one*.

---

If you really really want to populate a `binary(12)` database value, then in C# terms you want a `byte[12]` value. If the contents of this is meant to be the *character* data (so the hex values 31-30-31-30-31-30-31-30-31-30-31-30), then it can be simple:

```cs
string s = "101010101010";
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
```

If, however, you intend the bytes to be the values 0/1 (i.e. the hex values 01-00-01-00-01-00-01-00-01-00-01-00) then you'll need something more like:

```cs
string s = "101010101010";
var bytes = new byte[s.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    bytes[i] = s[i] switch
    {
        '0' => 0x00,
        '1' => 0x01,
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected value: " + s[i]),
    };
}
```

(in either case, `bytes` is the value to send to the database)